# Javascript Draw Rect Borders

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I am trying to make a rect border that goes on top of an existing rect border. However, the new rect goes under the old one.

This is what happens:

[image]

I am trying to make the blue border cover the red dots.

clearRect doesn't work, as I'm only trying to cover the red dots, not fill the part box in.

```
var removeLast = function(l) {
    var that = {};

    that.draw = () => {
        rectMode(CENTER);
        strokeWeight(5);

        stroke(0,255,255);
        noFill();
        rect(that.getX(), that.getY(), that.getWidth(), that.getHeight());
        l.draw();
    }
    return that;
}
```

Comment: can you include more code please?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Note that this should **not** be your full program. It should be just enough code to reproduce the problem.